# Why doesn't my DNS change propagate within the TTL?

Tags: networking, google-chrome, dns, ipv4, dig

Why isn't my DNS propagating correctly? It has a TTL of 3600 seconds, 1 hour, yet it is still resolving to an old IP. It's been at least 10 hours! http://www.onlinedig.com/go-dig/

```
C:\>nslookup pixycars.com
Server:  rns1.earthlink.net
Address:  207.69.188.185

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    pixycars.com
Addresses:  fe80::601:20ff:fe9a:cf01
          192.185.236.196
```

What's weird is the new IPV6 address record is showing up. What's worse is Chrome randomly uses the new IP or old IP and there's no rhyme or reason! chrome://net-internals/#dns

Comment: Check http://www.digwebinterface.com/?hostnames=Pixycars.com&type=A&useresolver=8.8.4.4&ns=all&nameservers=. Its showing 2 dif IPs depending on the server that is queried. Some take more time to propagate. You want to set your TTL low well before you make the record change so that DNS will know to query your nameservers sooner.

Comment: Neat! Now that's what I'm talking about! I thought 1 hour should be enough? So some DNS servers just ignore it?

Comment: Yes some do seem to cache them for longer. Where i work, we try to lower it to 1 min, if possible, a few days before changing any records. Of course, that's not always possible.